# API Gateway call to Lambda {proxy+} function - Internal Server Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have an API Gateway with the following API endpoint:

[image]

When I try to test it I get the following error:

```js
Request: /connect/list_users
Status: 500
Latency: 29 ms
Response Body
{"message": "Internal server error"}
Response Headers
{"x-amzn-ErrorType":["InternalServerErrorException"]}
Logs
Execution log for request 3ff47544-2f03-4e52-a52c-ce76e397aee7
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Starting execution for request: 3ff47544-2f03-4e52-a52c-ce76e397aee7
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /connect/list_users
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Method request path: {proxy=list_users}
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Method request query string: {}
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Method request headers: {}
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Method request body before transformations: 
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:connect_api/invocations
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Endpoint request headers: {X-Amz-Date=20230531T155255Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=xxxxxxxxxxxx, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_xxxxxxxxxxxx, Host=lambda.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com, X-Amz-Content-Sha256=xxxxxxxxxxxx, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-64776d57-xxxxxxxxxxxx, x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=xxxxxxxxxxxx, Authorization=*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ca4e12, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx/test-invoke-stage/GET/connect/{proxy+}, X-Amz-Security-Token=xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx [TRUNCATED]
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/connect/{proxy+}","path":"/connect/list_users","httpMethod":"GET","headers":null,"multiValueHeaders":null,"queryStringParameters":null,"multiValueQueryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":{"proxy":"list_users"},"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"resourceId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","resourcePath":"/connect/{proxy+}","httpMethod":"GET","extendedRequestId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx=","requestTime":"31/May/2023:15:52:55 +0000","path":"/connect/{proxy+}","accountId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","stage":"test-invoke-stage","domainPrefix":"testPrefix","requestTimeEpoch":xxxxxxxxxxxx,"requestId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"cognitoIdentityId":null,"apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","principalOrgId":null,"cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"userArn":"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx.com","apiKeyId":"test-invoke-api-key-id","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, li [TRUNCATED]
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Sending request to https://lambda.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:connect_api/invocations
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function
Wed May 31 15:52:55 UTC 2023 : Method completed with status: 500
```

Now, this is the policy attached to the IAM role for the Lambda function that calls the DynamoDB table:

```js
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "connect:ListRoutingProfiles",
                "connect:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:connect:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance/xxxxxxxxxxxx/contact-flow/*/*",
                "arn:aws:connect:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance/xxxxxxxxxxxx/contact-flow/*",
                "arn:aws:connect:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance/xxxxxxxxxxxx/*",
                "arn:aws:connect:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:instance/xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ],
            "Sid": ""
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:connect_api"
        },
        {
            "Action": "dynamodb:Query",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/contactlens/index/timestamp",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/contactlens"
            ],
            "Sid": ""
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:GetItem"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/ctr",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/agent_status"
            ],
            "Sid": ""
        },
        {
            "Action": "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/agent_status",
            "Sid": ""
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

And this is the policy attached to the IAM role for the API Gateway to call the Lambda function:

```js
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Scan"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/customers",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/accounts",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/cards",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/sinistres",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/email",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/appointment_slots",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/agencies",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/intent_history",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/authorization_requests",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/ctr",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/agent_status",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/missed_calls"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:treat_authorization_request"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

For the sake of clarity, this is how I test this API:

[image: API Gateway test]

Finally, if I test the Lambda function in the test environment of the Lambda console, it works fine, so I suppose this means that the problem is not between the function and the DynamoDB table, but if I test the API call from the API Gateway I get the error of above.

Do you have any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Why does the 2nd IAM policy allow API Gateway to access DynamoDB tables and CloudWatch Logs? All it should need is permission to invoke the Lambda function afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
If I go to the API Gateway console -> my API Endpoint -> /connect method -> ANY -> Integration Requests:

[image: API Gateway Console]

then I simply click in Lambda Function (the pencil symbol) like I want to modify the selected function and I try to save the selected function keeping the same one (connect_api), a new window will pop up before saving it:

[image: Permission to Lambda Function]

then you click "ok" and the API works fine.

So basically seems a problem in the policy associated to the IAM role used by the API Gateway.

Now the question is, how should I change the policy in order to avoid to add the permission to the API Gateway from the API Gateway Console?

This AWS documentation helped me: [AWS Internal Server Error troubleshoot](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-http-lambda-integrations)

Answer (score 1):

Your API Gateway execution role only has permission to invoke a Lambda function named `treat_authorization_request`, but that API seems to be invoking a function named `connect_api`.

What happens if you update the policy like this?

```
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:*"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. It points out what is almost certainly the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Payton for the answer, I have tried with your suggestion but still doesn't work, if I test the API in API Gateway after having modified the policy according to your suggestion, I still have the Internal Server Error. Anyway, I was thinking that maybe the problem is not related to policy misconfiguration, could be that is simply a mistake in the path that I specify in API Gateway when I test it (I have added other information in the post, also the python code of the lambda function).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is experiencing this problem. Make sure you **return properly formatted json response** in your lambda. For me the problem was that I didn't have payload in body. Also keep in mind that the **limit for the body in Lambda is** **1MB**

I changed
`return {statusCode: 200, result: "Hello world"}`

to

`return {statusCode: 200, body: "Hello world"}`

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway